# How to make the output of list in lisp nicer?

Tags: lisp, listener, lispworks

I declared the following list in lisp:

```
  (defvar car-owners-2 (list (list 'yaakov (list 'volvo 100000.0)) 
                             (list 'moshe (list 'vw 75000.0)) 
                             (list 'rachel (list 'mazda 60000.0)) 
                             (list 'sarah (list 'volvo 100000.0)) 
                             (list 'david  (list 'renault 50000.0))
                             (list 'leah  (list 'vw 75000.0))))
```

and when I want to see it from the listener file I get this disgusting output:

```
 CL-USER 19 : 6 > car-owners-2
    (((QUOTE YAAKOV) (QUOTE (# 100000.0))) ((QUOTE MOSHE) (QUOTE (# 75000.0))) 
    ((QUOTE RACHEL) (QUOTE (# 60000.0)))   ((QUOTE SARAH) (QUOTE (# 100000.0)))
    ((QUOTE DAVID) (QUOTE (# 50000.0)))    ((QUOTE LEAH) (QUOTE (# 75000.0))))
```

How can I make the output normal? And why instead of names it prints #?
I want the output to be like this:

```
((YAAKOV (VOLVO 100000.0)) (MOSHE (VW 75000.0)) (RACHEL (MAZDA 60000.0))...)
```

Thanks.
I use LispWorks 6.0.1

Comment: In clozure CL and my lispworks personal 6.0.1 the output looks normal...Did you mistype something??

Comment: no..the output that is shown here was copied from my listener file..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe create the same list this way:

```
> '((yaakov (volvo 100000.0))
    (moshe (vw 75000.0))
    (rachel (mazda 60000.0))
    (sarah (volvo 100000.0))
    (david (renault 50000.0))
    (leah (vw 75000.0)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but you were right before. It gives a fine output. But for sure there is some problem with loading .lisp to lispworks' listener.. Everytime I make a change in my .lisp file I have to reopen lispworks and then load it..very annoying.

Comment: you can re-evaluate the changed expression, then you don't have to reload.

Comment: @זאבי כהן: Or, better, use defparameter instead of defvar. With defparameter, it sets the value at every evaluation, with defvar only if the variable doesn't have a value.

Answer (score 2):

> CL-USER 19 : 6 >

First I would go out of the debugger.

This would be the usual prompt:

> CL-USER 19 >

The `19` says that it is the 19th form read. The `: 6` above means that you are in a debugger and the 6th form in the debugger is read.

> CL-USER 19 : 6 > :top

`:top` brings you to the top-level.

Then check the value of variables like `*print-level*` and `*print-length*`.

```
CL-USER 12 > (setf *print-level* 2)
2

CL-USER 13 > (list (list 'yaakov (list 'volvo 100000.0)) 
                             (list 'moshe (list 'vw 75000.0)) 
                             (list 'rachel (list 'mazda 60000.0)) 
                             (list 'sarah (list 'volvo 100000.0)) 
                             (list 'david  (list 'renault 50000.0))
                             (list 'leah  (list 'vw 75000.0)))
((YAAKOV #) (MOSHE #) (RACHEL #) (SARAH #) (DAVID #) (LEAH #))

CL-USER 14 > (setf *print-level* nil)
NIL

CL-USER 15 > (list (list 'yaakov (list 'volvo 100000.0)) 
                             (list 'moshe (list 'vw 75000.0)) 
                             (list 'rachel (list 'mazda 60000.0)) 
                             (list 'sarah (list 'volvo 100000.0)) 
                             (list 'david  (list 'renault 50000.0))
                             (list 'leah  (list 'vw 75000.0)))
((YAAKOV (VOLVO 100000.0)) (MOSHE (VW 75000.0))
 (RACHEL (MAZDA 60000.0)) (SARAH (VOLVO 100000.0))
 (DAVID (RENAULT 50000.0)) (LEAH (VW 75000.0)))
```